# JBWEB000250: Child container with name already exists

Tags: tomcat, ant, jboss

I had deployed the ear in JBoss which consists of few war (Web Archive). Basically the deployed ear file was built by ant by setting TOMCAT_HOME prior to start the ant build.

```
set TOMCAT_HOME=C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32
```

I'm getting following error. I deployed it in JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21)

> 11:38:34,340 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: Failed to start service
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1936) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000250: Child container with name  already exists

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000250: Child container with name  already exists
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:794)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:785)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:353)
>       at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:62)
>       at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.inject(WebContextInjector.java:38)
>       at org.jboss.msc.inject.CastingInjector.inject(CastingInjector.java:55) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.doInject(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1704) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$2000(ServiceControllerImpl.java:52) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.performInjections(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1949) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1908) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>       ... 3 more

This project is a legacy project. It has Struts 1.2.9, Springs-2.0.8, Hibernate-3.2.6 jar files in project lib directory and configurations for the same are available under \WEB-INF\ of Web Archives (.war).

Basically I am porting the Application from Websphere to JBoss

How can I solve or overcome this issue.

Comment: I hope this problem occurs because of occurrence of same .war file in both .ear file as well as inside of some .war file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In standalone.xml this will be true `enable-welcome-root`. If you make it false you can deploy a web archive `.war` in the `/` context....

If `enable-welcome-root` remains true, then some default jboss web page comes. Hence this needs to be corrected to deploy a web application in `/` context.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because of occurrence of same .war file in both .ear file as well as inside of some .war file.

In my case .war has a recurrence as a jars with the same name of some .war files under one .war\WEB-INF\lib. And those .jar's has everything replicated except `web` folder removed. I hope this has been done to refer some java files across. NOW, I had removed those .jars. And now I am not getting this specific error.

So, for now, I sorted out this error `JBWEB000250: Child container with name already exists..`

There is nothing harm in building ant targets by setting TOMCAT_HOME.

But it may have some implications as Web Container varies.

Comment: This wasn't the issue as I need to put the compiled server side classes as `.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib/` as there is spring IOC container been used in my APP

Answer (score 0):

JBoss is not allowing to deploy any .war in `/` context.... We should give some web context name... for example `/scweb` or so..... Then it succeeds....

`.ear\META-INF\application.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd"
        version="1.4">
        <display-name>PCB Application</display-name>
        <module>
            <web>
                <web-uri>scWeb-1.1.war</web-uri>
                <context-root>/scWeb</context-root>
            </web>
        </module>
    </application>
```

I hope there is some `default-host` deployed in `/`

For that reason only I hope it says like....

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000250: Child container with name already exists

To overcome this error I removed all `.jar` server side classes which were put for dependency injections..... Later I realized that `.jar` wasn't the cause of the error.... I was confused as this error had come for some web-context as well... That maybe because of fast interpretation of error probably and I am not sure....

This error was just for the `default-host`.... Or it maybe because I have some `lm-shared.jar` under  `.ear\META-INF\lib`

Correct me if am wrong.... Give me some write-up, if cause of this error can be something else....

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem just stop the server JBOSS, navigate to the directory server within standalone / deployments and delete the .war project. Then just add the project again on the server and you are done.